# Do ED-E's weapons work in casinos?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

I'm about to go meet Benny in his suite at the Tops and, frankly, I don't trust him to come alone and unarmed to our little meeting.  I won't be arriving empty-handed myself - I've got a quiet .22 and a whole armload of grenades, but rule 1 of a gunfight is [bring all your friends who have guns](http://www.thegunzone.com/gunfighting.html).  Naturally, I thought of ED-E, who has them *built in*.

**Can ED-E use weapons in areas where they are ordinarily prohibited, specifically casinos?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes**. Ed-E's built in weapons are considered *[holdout weapons](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Holdout_weapons)*, which can be carried into a Casino. In addition, *any* human companion can carry *any* holdout weapon that the Courier's sneak skill will allow. So you can give a .22 to your buddy Boone as well, (for example).

However, according to the "bugs" section at the bottom of the page, ED-E's integrated weapons can be brought into weapons-free areas as holdout weapons only if the player's Sneak skill is below 50. This is caused by ED-E's weapons being included on the holdout weapons list but not the improved holdout weapons list.

Comment: I seem to remember that the improved ED-E weapons did have a bug when entering casino's either getting the weight added up each time, or not getting the weapon back. Or something.

Comment: I edited this to add the "bugs" section from the page you linked.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but ED-E dies very easily. Maybe you prefer to go with Lily. Or, what is my favorite strategy when I'm willing to kill Benny inside the casino, you can refuse to hand you weapons at entrance and go berserk. It may sound suicide but actually it will be easier this way, because you (and your companion) can use any weapons you have and use the entrance counter and the wall as a shield. By the way, you do not need kill Benny at that moment: if he escapes he will be captured by Caesar and eventually you will face him again.